# Use of unassigned local variable 'a'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am Learning c#, but suddenly the compiler in c# express edition 2008 says Use of unassigned local variable 'a', even with the simplest codes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int a;
a++;
Console.WriteLine(a);

}
}
}
```

That one gave an error.

Answer (score 5):

You have to initialize (assign something to) your `a` variable before you can use it. Basically compiler doesn't know what is a *starting* value of a variable. In this case it doesn't know the value of `a`, you have to assing something to it:

```
int a = 0;
a++;
```

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere, next time make sure that you understand compiler message :)

Comment: i thought that if you did not give a variable a value, it will automaticlly be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Before Initializing the value to the variable you cannot increment or decrement it.
so initialize it. The use it.